# How to show text fields from a User object to anonymous users without "View User Profile" permission?

Tags: 8, theming, users

I have a few basic fields on the user object to display "Author Bio" cards at the bottom of articles. It seems that anonymous users cannot see any of this information.

All I want to do is show first name, last name, phone number and email address. Is this hidden away because it requires "View User Profile" permission? How can I get around enabling that? I don't want to enable that if I don't have to. Conversely, how I can prevent anyone from getting to user/* pages?

Is there something I can change in the render array to change the access check?

Comment: Attaching a View to the content type with [EVA](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva) and providing the node author for a contextual filter?

Comment: Hmmm... so it’s already a View Block in a region on the page, let me check the settings

Comment: The EVA display would be if you want to include this in a view mode of the content type (can be displayed in multiple nodes on the same page). A view block display with a contextual filter is OK, if you want to display this for the author of the current node (then of course only for one node at the same time).

Comment: This is coming from a user reference field actually, not the node author core field. The field is set to render the user entity in a given view mode, the view Block is looking at the current node for the field value to render it in a block display.

Comment: In this case it might be easier if you switch the view to field mode and add a relationship to the referenced user, then all field values should be available.

Answer (score 1):

> Conversely, how I can prevent anyone from getting to user/* pages?

Getting technical here, you wouldn't want to block all `/user/*`; otherwise, you wouldn't be able to `/user/login` or `/user/logout` and also you would still want admins to access those `/user/{uid}` pages.

If  you inspect core/modules/user/**user.routing.yml** you can see most of the user routes. But what you expect, the `/user/{uid}` is not defined here.

It's actually defined in **UserRouteProvider.php** as `/user/{user}`

[image]

You can easily find the route name by enabling WebProfiler module that comes with [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and  going to `/user/1`

[image]

Now all you gotta do is override the route's access by giving it a role of administrator.

**mymodule/src/Routing/RouteSubscriber.php**

```
namespace Drupal\mymodule\Routing;
    
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

/**
 * Listens to the dynamic route events.
 */
class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    // Allow only admins to access '/user/{user}'.
    if ($route = $collection->get('entity.user.canonical')) {
        $route->setRequirement('_role', 'administrator');
    }
  }

}
```

Alternatively, in your custom module, you could create a new permission and use that for the Route's `setRequirement` instead and then assign the new permission to the roles that you want to have access.

**mymodule/mymodule.services.yml**

```
services:
  mymodule.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\Routing\RouteSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

For more in depth information about altering routes, see: [Altering existing routes and adding new routes based on dynamic ones](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones).

Comment: Yeah, when I said that I basically meant I did not want any non authenticated user to be able to access the user pages beyond login or forgot password. At the same time I really don't want _anyone_ to get there even if they are authenticated, and this might be the only path.

Comment: @Kevin yeah I figured, I only stated that for correctness; for the sake of non expert readers who might see this.

Comment: @Kevin curious to know what you ended up doing.

Comment: Wound up giving the permission for the short term until we have time to try this